# Update Manager on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: updates

I can't find the Update Manager when I tried searching it on the Dash Home bar. Help please?

Comment: try sudo apt-get update, it might help you out.

Comment: Ok, can you give me directions on how to do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Righthand side, select the cog wheel. Choose system settings.

Example:

[image]

Besides the "updates available" in the drop down see also "software sources" (for settings on when there should be a check on updates).

The "updates available" will do what Osama Jaber posted for command line :)

Comment: Ok, thanks, but I don't have the updates available in the drop down menu. Also, how do you access the command? Sorry for all the questions!

Answer (score 2):

Open Terminal and type the following

```
gksu update-manager
```

It will ask for the Password .Enter the password and update Manager will appear